# Calling an API inside another API returns Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm setting up some API, i need to call from one API another API which is already configured.
This is the the one i have to call:

```
exports.createNews = function (req, res, next) {
var notification = new Notification(req.body);

notification.save(function (err, notification) {
    if (err)
        return res.send(new Error(500, "There was a problem creating the notifications", err));

    res.send({
        success: true,
        data: {
            notification: notification
        }
    });
});
```

};

And this is the API which call the other:

```
feedback.save(function (err, feedback) {
                if (err)
                    return res.status(400).send(new Error(400, "Validation failed. Invalid attributes", err));

                var notification = new Notification()

                createNews(req,res,function () {
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        success: true,
                        data: {
                            feedback: feedback
                        }
                    });
                })
            })
```

I get this error: 
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

The problem is that i have to call also the first call alone.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `res.send` twice once within `createNews` and once within `feedback.save`.
The error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` usually means that you have already sent response once, and for obvious reasons you can not send response again.
So what you need to do is to send response only from one function either `createNews` or `feedback.save`.
Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I know, in fact the problem is that i have to call both alone too.

Comment: well you could either 
1. make two separate functions for the business logic and api logic of each and all them independently.
OR
2. Pass in another argument as a boolean and write if conditions to specify when to send response and when not to.